# How can I get the hostname for the Real Time Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

ga:hostname is available for the non-rt api. Where is rt:hostname?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

This is critical for me since I'm working on a site with different subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

Ya, it looks like that dimension isn't available in the Real Time Reporting API. Sounds like you want to make a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list